# Can we Integrate Cube report from different DB Server with SP2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, reporting-services

We have a standalone farm Installation of SharePoint 2013. All the below components are on single server say **Server1**:

**SharePoint 2013**

**SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)**

I want to integrate cube reports from **Server2** which is not added in the farm but it's in the same organizational network. Is above scenario possible just by adding .rdl files and DataSource Connection to a library?

Do I need to add the **Server2** as a part of SharePoint farm and install SharePoint foundation on it? Any help would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by 'same organizational network', you mean that server2 is in the same domain. I'd create new data source(s) that point to the cube(s) on server2.
Then start report builder from your SharePoint site. Then from report builder open your RDL's one by one. Point the data source to your SharePoint data source and save the RDL to your new report library in SharePoint.